# Error executing Apache BEAM sql query - Use a Window.into or Window.triggering transform prior to GroupByKey

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

**How do I include Window.into or Window.triggering transform prior to GroupByKey in BEAM SQL?**

I have following 2 tables:

Ist table

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
field1 varchar 
,field2 varchar
)
```

2nd Table

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
field1 varchar
,field3 varchar
)
```

And I am writing the result in a 3rd Table

```
CREATE TABLE table3(
field1 varchar
,field3 varchar
)
```

First 2 tables are reading data from a kafka stream and I am doing a join on these tables and inserting the data into the third table, using the following query. The first 2 tables are un-bounded/non-bounded

```
INSERT INTO table3 
        (field1, 
         field3) 
SELECT a.field1, 
   b.field3 
FROM   table1 a 
   JOIN table2 b 
     ON a.field1 = b.field1
```

I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GroupByKey cannot be
>   applied to non-bounded PCollection in the GlobalWindow without a
>   trigger. Use a Window.into or Window.triggering transform prior to
>   GroupByKey.   at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.applicableTo(GroupByKey.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:204)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.expand(GroupByKey.java:120)
>     at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)    at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:472)    at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:286)    at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey.expand(CoGroupByKey.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.CoGroupByKey.expand(CoGroupByKey.java:74)
>     at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)    at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:472)    at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.join.KeyedPCollectionTuple.apply(KeyedPCollectionTuple.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.joinlibrary.Join.innerJoin(Join.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.rel.BeamJoinRel.standardJoin(BeamJoinRel.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.rel.BeamJoinRel.buildBeamPipeline(BeamJoinRel.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.rel.BeamProjectRel.buildBeamPipeline(BeamProjectRel.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.rel.BeamAggregationRel.buildBeamPipeline(BeamAggregationRel.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.rel.BeamIOSinkRel.buildBeamPipeline(BeamIOSinkRel.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.planner.BeamQueryPlanner.compileBeamPipeline(BeamQueryPlanner.java:127)
>     at
>   com.dss.tss.v2.client.BeamSqlCli.compilePipeline(BeamSqlCli.java:95)
>     at com.dss.test.v2.client.SQLCli.main(SQLCli.java:100)

Comment: Can you post what the pipeline code looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is current implementation limitation of Beam SQL. You need to [define windows](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/windowing-and-triggering/) and then [join the inputs per-window](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/joins/#join-unbounded-unbounded).

Couple of examples of how to do joins and windowing in Beam SQL:

- [complex SQL query](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d906270f243bb4de20a7f0baf514667590c8c494/sdks/java/nexmark/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/nexmark/queries/sql/SqlQuery5.java#L58) with `HOP` window and joins;
- [test](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d906270f243bb4de20a7f0baf514667590c8c494/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlDslJoinTest.java#L175) which defines a window in Java outside of SQL and then applies query with join;
- examples of other window functions can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d906270f243bb4de20a7f0baf514667590c8c494/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlDslAggregationTest.java#L323);

**Background**

The problem is caused by the fact that it's hard to define Join operation for unbounded data streams in general, it is not limited to Beam SQL.

Imagine, for example, when data processing system receives inputs from 2 sources and then has to match records between them. From high level perspective, such system has to keep all the data it has seen so far, and then for each new record it has to go over all records in the second input source to see if there's a match there. It works fine when you have finite and small data sources. In simple case you could just load everything in memory, match the data from the sources, produce output.

With streaming data you cannot keep caching it forever. What if data never stops coming? And it is unclear when you want to emit the data. What if you have an `outer join` operation, when do you decide that you don't have a matching record from another input?

For example see the [explanation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey-and-unbounded-pcollections) for the unbounded `PCollections` in [`GroupByKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey) section of the Beam guide. And Joins in Beam are usually implemented on top of it using [`CoGroupByKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey) (Beam SQL Joins as well).

All of these questions can probably be answered for a specific pipeline, but it's hard to solve them in general case. Current approach in Beam SDK and Beam SQL is to delegate it to the user to solve for concrete business case. Beam allows users decide what data to aggregate together into a [window](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing), how long to wait for [late data](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data), and [when to emit](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers) the results. There are also things like [state cells](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html) and [timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) for more granular control. This allows a programmer writing a pipeline to explicitly define the behavior and work around these problems somewhat, with (a lot of) extra complexity.

Beam SQL is implemented on top of regular Beam SDK concepts and is bound by the same limitations. But it has more implementations of its own. For example, you don't have a SQL syntax to define triggers, state, or custom windows. Or you cannot write a custom `ParDo` that could keep a state in an external service.

Comment: "you don't have a SQL syntax to define triggers, state, or custom windows"

Can we not specify the Window.into or Window.triggering through just Beam sql?because I skimmed through the documentation and could find how to include triggering through sql

Comment: You cannot specify triggers directly in SQL query itself. Triggers have to be applied to the input `PCollections` before applying SQL. Recent versions of Beam SQL respect the triggers that were specified on the inputs and keep them unchanged. I see that you are not using Beam SQL directly but some wrapper (BeamSqlToraCli) that is not part of Beam SDK. This wrapper can potentially expose additional features for solving this, like allowing setting triggers in a different way.

Comment: If you have access to the input `PCollections` in Java code, then you certainly can set custom triggering and windowing yourself before applying the SQL query. My second example shows exactly that.

Comment: By Beam SQL not supporting custom windows I meant it does not allow creating new kinds of windows. You can use one of three supported windowing functions in `GROUP BY` clause: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/windowing-and-triggering/ but nothing extra, you cannot even specify allowed lateness. In Java pipelines (or Java+SQL) you can invent your own windows with granular control over them. And again, the tools you are using that wrap Beam SQL can potentially expose additional features, like allowing extra parameters for windows configuration, I don't know that part.

Comment: INSERT INTO ….
SELECT … FROM
(SELECT … FROM table1 WHERE … GROUP BY …) A
JOIN
(SELECT … FROM table2 WHERE … GROUP BY …) B
ON …

Comment: I was able to join the tables using ^^ this query.